# Android ndk library not push perfectly to the github

Tags: android-studio

I'm working on a android studio project which has NDK library. I clone the project:
git clone https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy.git
follow the instruction for making swig and after that I modify it little bit and I like to commit it to my own repository in GitHub.
but the problem is after I make a change to the project and try to commit it, it seems not all file committed completely because when I clone it from my repository it's give me this error

> Error:Could not list contents of '/Users/xxxxx/test1/SnowboyAlexaDe/src/main/jniLibs'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

any help would be appreciate.